# Signal-Slot connection after destruction of qml objects?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

What happens with the connection of signals from c++ objects to qml objects slots after destruction of qml objects?

```
Item {

    function qmlFunction() {
        cppObject.cppObjectFunction() 
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        cppObject.someSignal.connect(qmlFunction);
    }

    Component.onDestruction: {
        cppObject.someSignal.disconnect(qmlFunction);
    }
}
```

Before I wrote Component.onDestruction with disconnect() the program displayed an error message:

```
qrc:/qml/xxxxxxxx.qml:77: TypeError: Cannot call method 'cppObjectFunction' of undefined
```

Is the disconnection of signals and slots not performed automatically?

---

Object cppObject "always" exist and passed to qml this way:

main.cpp

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
Model* model = new Model::instance(&engine);
engine.setObjectOwnership(model, QQmlEngine::CppOwnership);
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("cppObject", model);
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/main.qml")));
```

QML item is loaded by the `Loader` and can be reloaded several times during the program. Naturally, the error occurs after the QML item has been reloaded and cppObject triggers a signal `someSignal`.

---

on windows: Qt 5.6.2   <- my program log error to debug console

on linux:   Qt 5.9.2   <- my program crashes

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
```

File with error

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
```

Comment: Please provide more code. From what I can see here, this shouldn't happen.

Comment: I could not find the answer is the doc. How is created `cppObject`? What is its lifetime compared to your Item?

Comment: Maybe a problem with the JS connections... Does the problem still arise when you use QML-style `Connections`?

Comment: If you'd provide a full minimal, complete and verifiable example, we might see, if there is mistake on your side, or whether it should be published on bugreports.qt.io

Comment: Added information about the life cycle of the cpp object. If I have time, I'll try to make a minimal project.

Comment: What is your Qt version?

Comment: added information about the qt version

Comment: @pier_nasos With the code that shows I have tried to reproduce its error and I do not have any problem, I have done it in Linux with Qt 5.10.1, only replace Model for a class that inherits from QObject.

Comment: @pier_nasos If you want us to help you, you must provide a [mcve], that code by definition must be complete, that is, without gaps, and yours must be patched everywhere. 
the error could be caused by the implementation of Model.

Comment: Whats on line 77 of `/qml/xxxxxxxx.qml` ??  thats where the error is...

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution is to :

istantiate the cppObject directly from QML to ensure that both objects are properly cleaned up by adding to your main.cpp file before you load the QML file

```
qmlRegisterType<Model>("com.your.app", 1, 0, "CppModel");
```

and then in your QML file include:

```
import com.your.app 1.0

....

CppModel {
     id: cppObject

     onSomeSignal:  { cppObject.cppObjectFunction(); }
}
```

This way will make the extra connections and the extra qmlFunction() both unnecessary.

and maybe this too:

If `cppObjectFunction()` is a public slot from  `cppObject` that is defined on the C++ side, you can try adding `Q_INVOKABLE` to the front of it in order to add it to the metaobject system.

```
Q_INVOKABLE void cppObjectFunction()  {  /* your code */ }
```